# WDS + GRUB2 UEFI: most menu items not working

Tags: wds, grub2, uefi

We are using WDS to deploy operating systems to several types of machines.
As per [this small guide](http://everdayadmin.blogspot.be/2017/04/setting-up-wds-to-pxe-boot-linux-uefi.html), I got the UEFI clients to boot grub, but most of the menu items aren't working.
When highlighting a selection and pressing enter, nothing happens, except for the selection highlight returning all the way to the top. (I suspect because it somehow failed, but I never really see any error that it can't do what I ask)

The menu cfg:

```
if loadfont $prefix/fonts/unicode.pf2
then
   set gfxpayload=keep
   set gfxmode=auto
   insmod efi_gop
   insmod efi_uga
   insmod gfxterm
   terminal_output gfxterm
   terminal gfxterm
fi

set default=0
set timeout=300
set check_signature=no

menuentry "Windows Deployment Services" --unrestricted {  
    insmod chain
    chainloader \Boot\x64\bootmgfw.efi
}

submenu "Tools" --unrestricted {
    menuentry "Display Workstation Networking Details" --unrestricted {
        echo "### NETWORKING ###"
        net_ls_addr
        echo "############"
        net_ls_cards
        echo "############"
        net_ls_routes
        echo "############"
        net_ls_dns

        echo "#"
        echo "#"
        echo "#"
        echo "Sleeping for 15 seconds. Press ESC to continue."
        sleep -iv 15
    }
}

menuentry "Reboot" --unrestricted {
    reboot
}
```

only the reboot option works.
Not even the "network tool", it just stays on the submenu and 
I tried replacing it with just echo's and that didn't change much.

Comment: are you able to see the mods in the CLI env? You might have a different CWD than is expected by your config.